# How do I search for nearby points in a bitmap without having to ignore exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net

```
private Point getNearestPointThatMatchesColorWithTolerance(Point i, Color color) {
    if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X, i.Y), color)) {
        return i;
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 1, i.Y), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 1, i.Y);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 1, i.Y), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 1, i.Y);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X, i.Y - 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X, i.Y - 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X, i.Y + 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X, i.Y + 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 1, i.Y - 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 1, i.Y - 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 1, i.Y - 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 1, i.Y - 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 1, i.Y + 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 1, i.Y + 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 1, i.Y + 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 1, i.Y + 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 2, i.Y - 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 2, i.Y - 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 1, i.Y - 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 1, i.Y - 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X, i.Y - 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X, i.Y - 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 1, i.Y - 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 1, i.Y - 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 2, i.Y - 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 2, i.Y - 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 2, i.Y + 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 2, i.Y + 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 1, i.Y + 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 1, i.Y + 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X, i.Y + 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X, i.Y + 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 1, i.Y + 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 1, i.Y + 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 2, i.Y + 2), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 2, i.Y + 2);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 2, i.Y + 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 2, i.Y + 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 2, i.Y), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 2, i.Y);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X + 2, i.Y - 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X + 2, i.Y - 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 2, i.Y - 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 2, i.Y - 1);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 2, i.Y), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 2, i.Y);
    } else if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(i.X - 2, i.Y + 1), color)) {
        return new Point(i.X - 2, i.Y + 1);
    } else {
        return Point.Empty;
    }
}
```

There are two problems with this method:

1. It has massive code duplication.
2. I am sometimes getting ArgumentOutOfRange errors because the parameters passed to haystack.GetPixel() are out of the bounds of the Bitmap haystack. I can add bounds checking but that would contribute even more to the code duplication discussed in point 1.

How do I fix this without ignoring exceptions?

Comment: If there's no reason for the order of the conditions in your `if` statements you could use a `loop` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare array of shifts and then iterate over it as long as no match is found:

```
public int[][] _shifts = {
    new [] { 0, 0 },
    new [] { 1, 0 }, new [] { -1, 0 }, new [] { 0, -1 }, new [] { 0, 1 }
    // (...)
};

private Point getNearestPointThatMatchesColorWithTolerance(Point i, Color color)
{
    var match = _shifts.Select(s => new Point(i.X + s[0], i.Y + s[1]))
                       .FirstOrDefault(s => colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(s.X, s.y), color));
    return match ?? Point.Empty;
}
```

To solve exceptions problem, you can easily extend that with `Where` condition:

```
private Point getNearestPointThatMatchesColorWithTolerance(Point i, Color color)
{
    var maxX = haystack.GetMaxX();
    var maxY = haystack.GetMaxY();

    var match = _shifts.Select(s => new Point(i.X + s[0], i.Y + s[1]))
                       .Where(s => s.X >= 0 && s.X <= maxX)
                       .Where(s => s.Y >= 0 && s.Y <= maxY)
                       .FirstOrDefault(s => colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(s.X, s.Y), color));

    return match ?? Point.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That is a large improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following. It avoids code duplication and the ArgumentOutOfRange exception.  The logic checks points from an increasing distance of the central point in a top-bottom/left-right order.

```
private Point getNearestPointThatMatchesColorWithTolerance(Point i, Color color) {

    for (int distance = 0; distance <= 2; distance++)
    {
        for (int x = i.X - distance; x <= i.X + distance; x++)
        {
            for (int y = i.Y - distance; y <= i.Y + distance; y++)
            {
                if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= haystack.Width || y >= haystack.Height)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (distance == 0 || i.Y - y == distance || y - i.Y == distance)
                {   // just borders need to be tested
                    if (colorsMatchWithTolerance(haystack.GetPixel(x, y), color))
                    {
                        return new Point(x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Point.Empty;
}
```

Note that there is no need to pre-build arrays and you can easily change the distance from the central point to find a match.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me fix another (similar) part of my program.

Comment: Wouldn't this give a bias to the lower left pixel as well as returning the first (rather than the nearest) match? Possibly adding a `List<Point>` and adding matches, then iterating through to find the closest match would be more preferable than returning the first match.

Comment: Note that `distance` controls the distance from the center. So, it tries to find the closest match first.

Comment: @wdosanjos Will this set of loops check points in exactly the same order as `if`/`else if`/`else` structure from OP does?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, well noted.  The code checks top-bottom/left-right, while OP seems to follow an _ad hoc_ order.  I added comments to the solution detailing the logic and I fixed an issue where the code was checking the same points multiple times.